# prove right and left limit

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a \in \mathbb R$ and let $f$ be a real-valued function defined on an open interval $J$ containing $a$. Then $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists if and only if the left-sided limit and the right-sided limit of $f$ exists and
$\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a^-} f(x)$

I want to ask how to prove this proposition converse direction?
That is, assume $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) \neq \lim_{x \to a^-} f(x)$ but $f$ is continuous at $a$?

Comment: It says "if and only if". So what you want to prove can't happen.

Comment: i know how to prove directly but i don't know how to prove converse side

Comment: Do you want to prove that if the one-sided limits don't agree, then the function is **not** continuous? In your question you asked for something different.

Comment: One does not prove a definition.  You may want to prove that some function exists meeting the definition, or that some function exists that does not meet the definition.

Comment: i have proved if side i want to ask how to prove only if side

Comment: To be honest, this result is standard, which means that you can find this in calculus and analysis text books or you easily google this in the web. Just take a time to do research. That's my advice rather than you wait for others to answer your question.

Comment: I think you misunderstand your object to prove the both directions.  First prove $\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x) = L \implies \lim_\limits{x\to a^+} f(x) = \lim_\limits{x\to a^-} f(x).$  Then prove $\lim_\limits{x\to a^+} f(x) = \lim_\limits{x\to a^-} f(x) \implies \lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x)$ exists.

Comment: sure i know that i was trying to do the contrapositive of the proposition. i don't think i misunderstand the question

Comment: You don't need contrapositive to prove it, See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484812/how-to-prove-that-if-the-one-sided-limits-are-equal-the-general-limit-is-that-va)