# If two one sided limits exist, the two sided limit exists.

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

prove that if the limit as x approaches a from the positive side of the x axis, f(x) = L, and if the limit as x approaches a from the negative side of the x axis, f(x) = L, then the limit as x approaches a of f(x) = L as well.

Comment: This is standard in just about every book, and readily available by Google searching the very title that you have here
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484812/how-to-prove-that-if-the-one-sided-limits-are-equal-the-general-limit-is-that-va

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You titled this "If two one sided limits exist, the two sided limit exists."  It should be "If two one sided limits exist, **and are equal**, the two sided limit exists."

In order to show that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)= L$, you want to show that, for any $\epsilon> 0$ there exist $\delta> 0$ such that if $|x- a|< \delta$ then $|f(x)- L|< \epsilon$.

Since $\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x)= L$ we know that, for any $\epsilon> 0$ there exist $\delta^-> 0$ such that if $x< a$ and $a- x< \delta^-$ then $|f(x)- L|< \epsilon$.

Since $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)= L$ we know that, for any $\epsilon> 0$ there exist $\delta^+> 0$ such that if $x> a$ and $a- x< \delta^+$ then $|f(x)- L|< \epsilon$.

So, given $\epsilon> 0$, take $\delta$ to be the smaller of $\delta^-$ and $\delta^+$ so that if $|x- a|< \delta$ then **both** $|x- a|< \delta^-$ and $|x- a|< \delta^+$ are true.  Whether $x> a$ or $x< a$, $|f(x)- L|< \epsilon$.